# Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated returns true for extranet\Anonymous user

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have Sitecore 6.6 installed. I wanted to add a new domain to Sitecore; Since my Sitecore instance is deployed in two servers with two Sitecore sites in each pointing to different web databases but same core, master and analytics databases, I couldn't do it using Sitecore Domain manager.So I thought of doing it manually by editting the App_Config\Security\domains.config in the server. The following was the domains.config that I had.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<domains xmlns:sc="Sitecore">
<domain name="sitecore" ensureAnonymousUser="false" />
<domain name="extranet" defaultProfileItemId="{AE4C4969-5B7E-4B4E-9042-B2D8701CE214}" />
<domain name="default" isDefault="true" />
<sc:templates>
    <domain type="Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <ensureAnonymousUser>true</ensureAnonymousUser>
        <locallyManaged>false</locallyManaged>
    </domain>
</sc:templates>
<domain name="Station" defaultProfileItemId="{F181ED3D-F342-46E6-B6F6-2A6A6173B513}" />
<domain name="Emailcampaign" />
</domains>
```

I added one more domain(MyDomain) at the end  like below.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<domains xmlns:sc="Sitecore">
<domain name="sitecore" ensureAnonymousUser="false" />
<domain name="extranet" defaultProfileItemId="{AE4C4969-5B7E-4B4E-9042-B2D8701CE214}" />
<domain name="default" isDefault="true" />
<sc:templates>
    <domain type="Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain, Sitecore.Kernel">
        <ensureAnonymousUser>true</ensureAnonymousUser>
        <locallyManaged>false</locallyManaged>
    </domain>
</sc:templates>
<domain name="Station" defaultProfileItemId="{F181ED3D-F342-46E6-B6F6-2A6A6173B513}" />
<domain name="Emailcampaign" />
<domain name="MyDomain" />
</domains>
```

As soon as I did that, Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated started returning true for extranet\Anonymous user(Non-logged in user) in the code.

Has anyone faced this issue before? 
Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: Have you pasted correct code for second configuration? I don't see any differences.

Comment: @Anton Sorry about that. Someone had editted the post and made some changes to it. Take a look at it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally resolved this issue! This was caused by a fix we added to solve an issue we had with Sitecore ECM. The issue was that Sitecore used to log out as soon as we clicked on the message preview. So we followed the steps given in the below thread to fix the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30836600/4165670

But we were not testing for Anonymous user like it is done in the thread. We never pushed this code into Content Delivery site and when 
we created the new domain, This code got pushed into the Content Delivery site with some other code.

Since we are setting the current user as the Active user in the code, it started showing that extranet\Anonymous user as the current user.

Answer (score 2):

I also encounted this issue back when I was working with Sitecore 6.6, I'm not certain if its an issue in later versions. Essentially when you modified your `domains.config` with the param `ensureAnonymousUser` set to true the Anonymous User for that domain, in this case Extranet, was created in the database - it may not have been until you changed that setting.

In Sitecore all non-logged in users view the site as the user `*domain*/anonymous`. As Sitecore's membership is based on .NET Membership it determines that the User is logged in as its using that account.

Therefore I recommend completing an additional check with your `Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated` to check if the username of User's account is `*domain of site*/anonymous`, `Sitecore.Context.User.Name`, if it is return false.

**EDIT**

I have confirmed `Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated` returning true for `*domain*\Anonymous` user has been fixed in Sitecore 8. Therefore you can use it to determine if the User is logged in and not using the `*domain*\anonymous` account.

Comment: In my case extranet\Anonymous user was already present before I made changes to domains.config and For non loggedin users I was getting the username as extranet\Anonymous and Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated as false. But as soon as I added a domain, For non loggedin users I started getting the username as extranet\Anonymous and Sitecore.Context.User.IsAuthenticated as true. The interesting thing is if I remove the new domain by deleting tha t domain saving the file it was still giving the same issue but only after I replaced the domains.config file with the old file. It started working.

Comment: Curious - what domain are you in when checking the Username and IsAuthenticated? If you are in your new MyDomain domain, you should be seeing non-loggedin users as MyDomain\anonymous not extranet\anonymous

Comment: I will be in extranet\Anonymous domain

Comment: Okay, well as I said in the answer Membership identifying default\anonymous as logged in is expected behaviour and is the case for all Sitecore 6.6 I've worked on and expect I to be the case for all subsequent releases. Therefore fix the issue by adding the check for *domain*\anonymous username I described in my answer